# Matching expression to data types involving dynamic 2d arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Okay this is a homework question I am having trouble with. I finished all the other questions and this is the last one I'm stuck on.

Assume variable `parkingLot` points to a dynamic 2D array of `Car` objects. Match each expression to its data type. One answer will be used twice.

```
 parkingLot[0][2]
 parkingLot+1
 parkingLot
 parkingLot[1]
```

Match to:
     a. `Car*`
     b. `Car**`
     c. `Car`

Can someone explain this one to me?

Answer (score 1):

Don't want to answer a homework question, so I'll try to be general. You have to think about it as levels. At the top level, you're looking down on the 2D array and you'll see both pointers. If you drill down one level, you'll still see the other pointer. At the bottom is the object itself.